# Grammatical Implications in "Opportunity" and "Possibility" Usage

Tags: difference, word-choice

> a.1) You have the *opportunity* to go to Norfolk next month.
>   a.2) *There is the *opportunity* of your going to Norfolk next month.
>
> b.1) *You have the *possibility* to go to Norfolk next month.
>   b.2) There is the *possibility* of your going to Norfolk next month.

How are these two words different in their own usage to refer to future events when they are used in sentences like those shown above?

[Searching on Google](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=opportunity%20to%20go,possibility%20of%20going&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) would prove that a.1) and b.2) are grammatical, but a.2) and b.1) are not. If so, why?

Answer (score 4):

First and foremost, all four of those sentences are in fact *grammatically* correct. What Google demonstrates is that a.2 and b.1 are really awkward and therefore *much* less common.

In terms of the *implications* of the words themselves:

**Opportunity** often implies that it is an offer being extend or provided to you by a specific entity or person who is *providing* you with means or privilege otherwise unavailable to you. Sometimes there is no other party offering the opportunity, but there is always the sense of urgency, that it is a limited time deal, something that must be seized or it will be lost. There is generally a positive connotation: an opportunity is a good thing, something to be excited about.

**Possibility** simple implies that it is something that **can** happen, either because you decide to make it happen or because circumstances cause it to happen. There is no implicit positive or negative connotation here. There is also no implicit implication of the likelihood of the event happening. If it is possible, it may or may not happen.

In general, opportunities imply possibility, but not the other way around. If you are given the opportunity to go to Norway, then of course it is possible. But if you lived within driving distance of Norway, you wouldn't usually refer to your possibility of driving there at any moment as an "opportunity".

Some examples:

> There is a distinct **possibility** that I may lose my job next week, but I have been given the **opportunity** to work at an exclusive Swedish design firm, so I'm not too bummed.
>
> I really needed to talk to my professor. He was a busy man, so this was nearly **impossible**, but I happened to see him walking alone one day, so I seized the **opportunity**.

Interestingly, [this Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=opportunity+to+go%2C+possibility+of+going%2C+possibility+to+go%2Copportunity+of+going&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) suggests that in fact the usage of "opportunity to go" and "opportunity of going" have reversed in the last 200 years, with both being approximately equal in use around AD 1890-1900.

Answer (score 2):

Although *opportunity* and *possibility* have similar meaning, they are quite different by usage and grammar:

- **Possibility** conveys a meaning that something might be true (both currently or in the future). It is used with  *of* or *that*:

> There is a possibility **that** our project will fail;
>   There is a possibility **of** project failure;

Note the former is a complete sentence but latter is a bare noun.

- **Opportunity** conveys a meaning that it is possible for someone **to accomplish some goal** (because of the luck or changed circumstances). It is used with a verb phrase:

> After graduation, I will have an *opportunity* **to** find a good job;

Compare:

> Despite the *possibility* of storms, I decided to take an *opportunity* to go to islands.

Note that *opportunity* usually means what someone is trying to accomplish, while *possibility* is just a matter or randomness.

Answer (score 2):

I would word your example sentences slightly differently. Specifically, I'd be more inclined to use an indefinite article, and I'd probably use the prepositional phrase *of you going* in lieu of *of your going*. Thus:

> a.1) You have an opportunity to go to Norfolk next month.
>    a.2) *There is an opportunity of you going to Norfolk next month.
>
> b.1) *You have a possibility to go to Norfolk next month.
>    b.2) There is a possibility of you going to Norfolk next month.

With that said, your hunch is correct about how *possibility* and *opportunity* should be used. **Possibilities** are more impersonal, and describe circumstances; **opportunities** are tied to something positive for an individual. One might say that people live *among* possibilities, but they *have* opportunities. So, I might write:

> There's a possibility I will get a new job.

or:

> I have an opportunity to get a new job.

but I wouldn't swap those words in that context.